# ASP.NET 4.5 Web App - Username/Password textboxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5

When I start ASP.NET Web Application in ASP.NET 4.5 / Visual Studio 2012, in its `Login.aspx` page, there are Username and Password textboxes and Log In button.

When I double click on button (in VS) it create click event in code.

When I try to use Username/Password boxes like this:

```
string username = Username.Text;
```

it says Username (the textbox) does not exists in current context.

Code `Login.aspx.designer.cs` almost empty.

```
namespace WebApplication2.Account
{


    public partial class Login
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// RegisterHyperLink control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink RegisterHyperLink;

        /// <summary>
        /// OpenAuthLogin control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::WebApplication2.Account.OpenAuthProviders OpenAuthLogin;
    }
}
```

`Login.aspx` html

```
<%@ Page Title="Log in" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.Account.Login" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
    </hgroup>
    <section id="loginForm">
        <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
        <asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                </p>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" />
                </fieldset>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
        <p>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Register</asp:HyperLink>
            if you don't have an account.
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="socialLoginForm">
        <h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
        <uc:OpenAuthProviders runat="server" ID="OpenAuthLogin" />
    </section>
</asp:Content>
```

Why those controls are not in designer.cs?

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something else in your project isn't building properly when it tried to create the Login.aspx.designer.cs file.

I've had this before, though not on the login page in a fresh project.

Generally, I delete the designer file (not the Login.aspx or Login.aspx.cs), then right-click Login.aspx and choose 'Convert to Web Application'. This will try to create the Login.aspx.designer.cs file with all of the correct contents.

If something is broke in your project that it depends on though, it will show you a error message telling you what is wrong... you can then fix the underlying problem in your project, and then try the 'Convert to Web Application' option again.

Hope this helps,

Kurt

Comment: Thanks, but I tried starting new project again, it is empty again. Tried deleting designer, and converting, and it's same again. It does not generate code for textboxes. I updated question with html code for login.aspx, maybe that can help...

Comment: Has the form not been edited at all? The loginform doesn't have an ID attribute:

Comment: This is original login form. And it's Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Here's the fix... Add an ID (for example ID="LoginForm") to the loginform control in the page then access user name using LoginForm.UserName

Comment: ^I just checked my solution and the files are identical to yours so there's nothing wrong with code-generation.

Comment: Did adding the ID="LoginForm" and using LoginForm.UserName resolve this for you?

Comment: Yes it did. You are legend.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try giving the controls the actual 'ID' property, as opposed to the AssociatedControlID="Whatever" property?

Answer (score 0):

There are two visible problems I can see:  I had a similar issue

1) string username = Username.Text; 
the 'n' in UserName is not capitalized, but intellisense would have caught that one
2) The aspx.cs file, in the first line is referring to an old file 'WebApplication5' (see below)

`Login.aspx.cs`

> 

While the namespace in your Designer.cs file refers to WebApplication2.   That leads me to believe that the Project name is out of sync with one of these two files.   Correct the reference, and you should be able to see Variables from file to file now.

`Login.aspx.designer.cs`

> namespace WebApplication2.Account

Hope that helps,
-Kevin